# How does Apigee cloud setup works with on-premises exposed services behind CAS?

Tags: proxy, cas, restful-architecture, apigee

I'm working on making enterprise API available to external customers. Apigee provides powerful features for selling API as a product and api monetization.

Use Case: We have our own on-premises CAS with LDAP implementation for SSO (single Sign-on) support among multiple apps. We have been planning to use API as a backend when making proxies in Apigee. for example
1- Create API proxy for each available backend service
2- Make API products using on fly using API proxies

Problem statement: what would be the API route when customers consume proxy layer available on Apigee cloud? for example
1- Apigee authenticate and authorize customers/developers on cloud when they access proxy layer
2- later proxy payer access the back-end service with consumer key
3- Backend service authenticate through on-premises CAS server using consumer key (assume account exist in LDAP as CAS working with LDAP) and initiate the session
4- Token is generated by CAS.... how customer or app developer  use that token for next call? keep in mind.. next call is another proxy that is setup on apigee (and in turn it uses any available backend service)

i assume, proxy call on agigee cloud looks as follow
...apigee.example.org/customer/....
while backend service call that talks to on-premises CAS looks as follows
...example.org/customer....

Thanks!

Comment: Thinking you might have better luck asking this question on the Apigee community site - SO is for programming and related questions, whereas yours is quite broad and architecture-oriented.

Answer (score -1):

**Apigee Delegated Token Management**

**Music OAuth 2.0 Delegated Authentication API Bundle**

This API bundle provides an example of an API Proxy secured-based resource by Delegated Token Service and Apigee. So, that an access token can be generated by a third party such as Google OAuth API and yet use the same token to restrict access to a resource on Apigee.

A typical use of this flow can be better described by the following sequence diagram:

[image]

Source: http://goo.gl/LgeuYw

**Apigee Delegated Token Management sample flow**

**Deploying API bundle with Grunt.js**

This API Bundle can be deployed by leveraging Apigee Deploy Grunt.js Plugin or via any tool that can import Apigee proxy bundles.

Step 1: Test oauth-delegated/generatetoken resource

The following command demonstrates how to send a request with an access token that gets stored by Apigee OAuthV2 Policy, and then used for subsequent requests.

In a real scenario, the client would never set the access token, however this example gives you an idea how to set the variables that will get stored in Apigee to be able to save them as the token instead of Apigee Generated token. Regardless of whether these values are generated either by the client or the server app preferably. An implementation closer to a more production one would make a request to an OAuth Provider, for instance Google OAuth Service and then store access and refresh tokens in Apigee as custom attributes. See suggestion provided from StackOverflow answer.

```
curl https://testmyapi-test.apigee.net/oauth-delegated/generatetoken\?external_access_token\=123456 \
-d 'client_id=sxnS7SddD6494Akbqk74ej4SmvvqjL0O&grant_type=client_credentials' -v
```

will produce:

```
      {
  "issued_at" : "1415467907287",
  "application_name" : "99d3f4de-e501-4836-9bdd-f552e1d4b923",
  "scope" : "WRITE",
  "status" : "approved",
  "api_product_list" : "[PremiumWeatherAPI]",
  "expires_in" : "1799",
  "developer.email" : "tesla@weathersample.com",
  "organization_id" : "0",
  "token_type" : "BearerToken",
  "client_id" : "sxnS7SddD6494Akbqk74ej4SmvvqjL0O",
  "access_token" : "123456",
  "organization_name" : "testmyapi",
  "refresh_token_expires_in" : "0",
  "refresh_count" : "0"
}
```

Note: Access token generated is the same as the access token sent in the cURL command from step 1.

**Step 2: Test /oauth-external/testtoken**

The following request tests that the access token "generated" in step 1 is valid to access a protected resource, in our case /music.

curl https://testmyapi-test.apigee.net/oauth-delegated/music\?func\=getSong\&artist\=radiohead\&fmt\=json -H 'Authorization:Bearer 123456'
will produce:

200 OK

```
  {
     "artist": "Radiohead",
       "albums": [
         {
           "album": "Pablo Honey",
           "year": "1993",
           }, ...
        ]
  }
```

**How did we get to store the token?**

Policies under apiproxy are defined to implement this behavior.

OAuth-v20-Verify-Token.xml Policy

Note a the following parameters parameters in this policy:

ExternalAuthoriation set to true
ExternalAccessToken set to request.queryparam.external_access_token. External access token is being provided in the request, however this parameter can be set with any other variable generated from an external token service.
StoreToken set to true. Otherwise the token will never be persisted.

```
<OAuthV2 async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="OAuth-v20-Verify-Token">
    <DisplayName>OAuth v2.0 1</DisplayName>
    <FaultRules/>
    <Properties/>
    <Attributes/>
    <ExternalAuthorization>true</ExternalAuthorization>
    <Operation>GenerateAccessToken</Operation>
    <SupportedGrantTypes> <!-- Optional -->
        <GrantType>client_credentials</GrantType>
    </SupportedGrantTypes>
    <GenerateResponse enabled="true"/>

    <ExternalAccessToken>request.queryparam.external_access_token</ExternalAccessToken>
   <StoreToken>true</StoreToken> 
    <Tokens/>
</OAuthV2>
```

**Assign-Message-Set-Variables.xml Policy**

This policy sets a variable required to enable external authorization.

```
<AssignVariable>
    <Name>oauth_external_authorization_status</Name>
    <Value>true</Value>
</AssignVariable>
```

**Run tests via Mocha**

Tests can be executed by either deploying the api with this command:

```
 grunt --env=test --username=$ae_username --password=$ae_password --debug
```

or running tests directly:

```
grunt mochaTest --env=test
```

Source: [My git repo.](https://github.com/dzuluaga/apigee-tutorials/tree/master/apiproxies/musicapi-oauth-delegated-authentication)